# MongoDB can not find documents that has two different fields which are including equal date

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, mongodb-query, mongo-shell, isodate

I was using Postgresql for my project, but lately I faced some performance problems and decided to try MongoDB. But this time I'm in the another sea of problems and I'm sinking.

The most important fields of my Table/Collection are "StartDate" and "EndDate"  because with these dates any post(s) in my database can be published on the site or removed from the site.

Here is my problem, I hope someone can help me :

When I'm inserting a post to database, I have two choices:

1) This post will never be removed from the site. In this situation I'm making "StartDate" and "EndDate" exactly same(equal). This means  that this post never be removed from the site, and it can be published at "StartDate".

2) This post can be/will be removed from the site. Of course, in this situation "StartDate" and "EndDate" are different, and based on these dates (between these dates) that the post can be published on the site.

Why this is important for me, because the tags of removed posts also need to be removed from tags page, the urls of removed posts also need to be removed from the sitemap etc...

In my postgresql tables this wasn't a problem and very simple query :

```sql
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE 
      SATUS=true AND (
        (enddate = startdate AND startdate <= Now()) 
        OR 
        (enddate <> startdate AND startdate <= Now() AND enddate > Now())
      )
```

But in MongoDB, I can not get the right results from my posts collection even if I use equivalent syntax?

I searched in the StackOverflow for days, and here is the most perfect aggregation syntax that I get. (for MongoShell)

The below query returns only the fields which has different "StartDate" and "EndDate" and currently publishing posts.

The first AND part of OR seem doesn't work. Only returns the second AND's results.

```js
var tmpDate = new Date();
db.getCollection('Posts').aggregate([
{ $project : {"_id":1,"Status":1,"EndDate":1,"StartDate":1}},
{ $match : 
    { "$and": [ 
        { "Status": true }, 
        { "$or": [
            { "$and": [{ "EndDate": { "$eq": "StartDate" } }, { "StartDate": { "$lte": tmpDate } } ] }, 
            { "$and": [ { "EndDate": { "$ne": "StartDate" } }, { "StartDate": { "$lte": tmpDate } }, { "EndDate": { "$gt": tmpDate } } ] } 
            ] 
        } 
        ] 
    }
}
])
```

Finally, I came across to answer about this situation at StackOverflow that MongoDB can not find equal dates or compare them like other DBs?

How can I accomplish this filtering? Or should I stay with Postgresql.

PS : I'm inserting test documents from an C# console application, and I'm inserting dates as ISO Dates :

```cs
DateTime tmpNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
tmpNow = Convert.ToDateTime(tmpNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:00")).ToUniversalTime();
```

I'm adding a sample document as requested :

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(1),
    "Status" : true,
    "Cat" : [ 
        4
    ],
    "Type" : 1,
    "Title" : {
        "Normal" : "Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia",
        "Spot" : null,
        "Small" : null,
        "Seo" : null
    },
    "Summary" : "Nam finibus nulla quis.",
    "Article" : "<p>Maecenas malesuada augue nec</p>",
    "Picture" : {
        "Path" : "/Content/Images/detay9.jpg",
        "Anchor" : "top",
        "Rank" : 0,
        "Desc" : null,
        "Width" : 843,
        "Height" : 1022
    },
    "Vertical" : null,
    "Source" : "StackOverflow",
    "Editor" : "An Editor",
    "Related" : null,
    "Tags" : [ 
        "Causae", 
        "Nusquam", 
        "Percipitur", 
        "Rihanna", 
        "Saglik"
    ],
    "StartDate" : ISODate("2019-05-05T13:44:00.000Z"),
    "EndDate" : ISODate("2019-05-05T13:44:00.000Z"),
    "UpdateDate" : ISODate("2019-05-05T13:44:00.000Z"),
    "Rank" : 100,
    "ReadCount" : 1064,
    "Gallery" : null,
    "List" : null,
    "Shared" : false,
    "Video" : null
}
```

Comment: Please add example data and describe what you mean by "But in MongoDB, I can not get the results from my posts collection". Is it empty? Is it wrong data? Does it emit an error?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the results. After a second check, I figured out that only the second AND operator is working and returning results. The first AND doesn't work. Which means posts that have same "StartDate" and "EndDate" doesn't return.

Comment: You want to return only those data which have same `StartDate` and `EndDate` . Is that  your problem ?

Comment: No, I want two types of posts for this reason I have two AND in my OR : 1) "StartDate" and "EndDate" are equal and lover than now(). and 2 ) "StartDate" and "EndDate" are different and "StartDate" lower than now(), "EndDate" greater than now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this, I hope it would work for you:

```
db.getCollection('Posts').aggregate([
    {
        $match:
        {
            "Status": true, "StartDate": { "$lte": tmpDate },
            $expr: { $or: [{ $eq: ['$StartDate', '$EndDate'] }, { $gt: ['$EndDate', tmpDate] }] }
        }
    },
    { $project: {"Status": 1, "EndDate": 1, "StartDate": 1 } }
])
```

**Note:**

1) In end result if you want **_id** then in `$project` you don't need to do `"_id":1` it would exist by default, you've to mention `"_id":0` if you don't want that field.

2) Going back to your statement : *`Finally, I came across to answer about this situation at StackOverflow that MongoDB can not find equal dates or compare them like other DBs?`*, From my experience I would say we can do if both fields are of same type, else you need to convert one to the other form, also if you're comparing two fields in mongoDB document using `$expr` will do the trick. It would be a nice to use `$match` as early as possible that way you'll filter documents and then do necessary operations.

Comment: Very Clever. I see that you've shortened my original sql query at first and move "startdate <= now()" condition to one level up because it's in both of AND sections. And then, you've also removed the "startdate <> enddate" because we are already checking their equality in OR's first part, that means if it doesn't match than it's not equal and we don't need to check again. Finally you only check "enddate > now()". And Yes your code works, I'm gratefull, Thank you very much. I think ```$expr```makes the magic happen in your code.